# how to create youtube subscribers bot in python

Tags: python, youtube

`import numpy as np` ( this is want i typed for line 7) but it shows errors , this is what it keep showing below

```
C:\Users\GOD\PycharmProjects\AddoProject\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\GOD\PycharmProjects\AddoProject\main.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\GOD\PycharmProjects\AddoProject\main.py", line 7, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
Process finished with exit code 1
```

so i tried to create youtube subscribers bot but am not able to continue with the projects

Comment: install numpy in your python ide.

Answer (score 0):

seems like your system does not recognize numpy, mostly you didn't install it

Open a terminal or command prompt and enter the following command:

```
pip install numpy
```